# How to prevent LastPass to autofill Magento's admin configuration while edit?

Tags: magento2, configuration, system.xml, system-config

The problem happens when you modify something in admin configuration in Magento 2 admin panel. The LastPass will autofill obscured fields and you will lose your data in these fields. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - extend class `Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field` by creating file `<Vendor>\<Module>\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\LastPassFix.php`. That functionality will add ignoring attribute to the field. Make sure to replace `<Vendor>` and `<Module>` placeholders. File content:

```
<?php

namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class LastPassFix extends Field
{
    /**
     * @param AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return $element->addCustomAttribute('data-lpignore', 'true')->getElementHtml();
    }
}
```

Then you have to modify `system.xml` in your extension by adding that string to obscured fields:

```
<frontend_model><Vendor><Module>\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\LastPassFix</frontend_model>
```

So it will be like this:

```
<field id="access_token" translate="label" type="obscure" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
     <label>Access Token</label>
     <frontend_model><Vendor>\<Module>\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\LastPassFix</frontend_model>
     <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted</backend_model>
</field>
```